# Unable to install the apk

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-4.4-kitkat

I am new to android development. I generated the signed apk successfully.It is getting installed in android higher versions successfully. 
But when I am trying to install in the android kitkat version, it's getting failed without any error message, once we click on the "install" button.
 App is successfully getting installed when tried using adb via command prompt, installation with debugging is also working fine. 
"Direct apk installation is failing in Kitkat"
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Does the devices which you have issues with have `Unknown sources` option enabled in the `Settings -> Security` menu? Are you using screen filtering apps? If yes, disable the screen filter app and it will work again. If you are not using any filtering app, try looking for screen-related apps installed on your phone. This kind of problem mostly related to screen-related apps. Try to disable them one by one in your `Settings->Apps` and find which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Unknown sources option is enabled. There are no screen filtering apps in the phone. I also have done factory data reset. Still the issue is seen

Comment: try this link then http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82155/why-cant-i-install-this-downloaded-apk

Comment: Will there be any screen related apps by default. I haven't installed any app after doing fact data reset.

Answer (score 0):

confirm you manifest file with following

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"     <!--min android version -->
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" /><!--higher android version -->
```